# Pointer casting in C what does the code mean

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
float number = 1.0;
float* number_pointer = &number;
int* int_pointer = (int*) number_pointer;                  
*int_pointer += 30;
printf("%f \n",number);
```

What does the line `(*int_pointer)+= 30;` do here?

Comment: By casting like that you're breaking [the strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). And using the pointer to `int` you will end up with undefined behavior, floating point values and integer values have different encodings in memory. To answer your question: The expression `*int_pointer += 30` does bad things, and may even cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: Many thanks. Will look into that strict aliasing rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two questions there.

1. What happens when you use

   ```
   int* int_pointer = (int*) number_pointer;
   ```

   That line takes the address of an object that holds a `float` and stores that address in `int_pointer`. At this point, the compiler will be able to treat the address as though it holds an integer. That constitutes a violation of the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).
2. What happens when you use

   ```
   *int_pointer += 30;
   ```

   It increments the value of the object that `int_pointer` points to by `30`. In cases where `int_pointer` points to a valid `int` object, that operation will be fine. In your case, this will cause undefined behavior since `int_pointer` really points to an object of type `float`.

Comment: Every possible pattern of bits is a valid int, so the += 30 will not fail. It will just scramble the bits of the float, possibly into an invalid representation, but probably not--the low-order bits of a float are all mantissa, so changing them will probably generate a perfectly valid float. It just won't bear much relationship to the "30" you ostensibly added.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain each statement:

```
float number = 1.0;
```

Here you have declared and initialized a float variable called `number`.

```
float* number_pointer = &number;
```

Declared and initialized float type pointer `number_pointer` to `number`. This means `number_pointer` holds the address of the variable `number` and `*number_pointer` gives the value of the variable `number`, i.e., `1.0`.

```
int* int_pointer = (int*) number_pointer;
```

Type-casted float pointer `number_pointer` to integer pointer and initialized to `int_pointer`. After this explicit type-casting, the value of `*int_pointer` is not  `1.0` but its corresponding integer `1065353216`.

```
*int_pointer += 30;
```

This is a short hand for `*int_pointer = *int_pointer + 30;`. `*int_pointer` becomes `1065353246`.

```
printf("%f \n",number);
```

Prints the value of `number`, which is now `1.000004` and not the initial `1.000000`. The change is caused by the addition performed on `int_pointer` which points to where `number_pointer` is pointing which in turn is the variable `number`.